# How to install a safety barrier-post in garage, between house and vehicle

Tags: concrete, walls, garage, safety, pole

On the other side of the wall, in front of where my vehicle is parked, is my bedroom.

Would like to install something similar to what you would see at store fronts that have parking spaces near the entrance.

Usually looks like 4' high, round pole, that goes into the concrete, [something like this](https://www.reliance-foundry.com/site/reliance-foundry/images/blog/posts/stainless-steel-bollard-covers-hospital.jpg).

Is this something that can be done by someone who has never done this but is handy?

...or what profession would do this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can rent a core drill for under 200 dollars including the dimond bit. You would need to make a substantially larger diameter hole than the pipe because you need concrete around it, not just in it.

This is a picture of a very serious bollard 
[image]
https://www.concreteconstruction.net/how-to/creating-a-bollard_o

If you are really worried about a teen driver or similar crashing into your bed, go with the example in the picture. A reasonable compromise with a fair amount of stopping power would be 2" pipe in a 6" hole at least a couple of feet deep. Most of the bolt down ones are just for show unless, you get some really serious anchors bolting down through a very thick peice of metal and deep into the concrete spread out on a large bolt pattern.

Comment: this is what I am looking for. Did not realize the pipe gets filled with the concrete also, guess that makes sense. Curious why/how 2" would be enough?

Answer (score 3):

You do not need a large core drilling rig if you get  surface mounted bollards.

If you are handy and have a hammer drill, You could do it with the Hammer drill and a [masonry drill bit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00004RHBT) to drill the holes for the anchors, and then use

[1/2 inch  Strong Bolt STB2-50512 Wedge Anchor 1/2-Inch by 5-1/2-Inch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0091N7TTM)

in the concrete to bolt the bollard down.

The length of the anchors will depend on the *thickness of the concrete slab*, if you have a thick slab then *use longer anchors for more strength*. Surface mounts are not going to be as beefy as core mounted but it will stop a car that is not moving to fast.

I have seen this method used for safety in front of boilers and water heaters in a garage. If you can get a bollard that has a wider base plate that will add strength/beefy-ness. Yea, i said beefyness.

or something like [this beefy guard](https://www.globalindustrial.com/p/safety/safety-guards-and-protectors/machine-guards-fixed/machinery-guard-round-48x48?presentType=98&trackCatKey=0&trackPrimKey=0&trackType=4&webCatKey=0)

Comment: that a good option as well, did not know about that, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> Would like to install something similar to what you would see at store fronts that have parking spaces near the entrance.  Usually looks like 4' high, round pole, that goes into the concrete, something like this.

Those are called *bollards.*

> Is this something that can be done by someone who has never done this but is handy?

If that handy person happens to own a large core drilling rig.

> ...or what profession would do this work?

Commercial parking lot paving contractors, some commercial general contractors.

Comment: learned a new word. Had to listen to its pronunciation as I kept saying "bowl-ard". Thanks, sounds doable.

Answer (score 2):

It would be a whole lot easier to put this type of vehicle barrier along the floor of the garage at the extreme position of where the tires of the vehicle would go. Concrete versions of these can be secured in place with construction adhesive and if desired a couple of short lengths of re-bar drilled down into the garage slab. Rubber ones may just need to be pinned in place.

[image]

<sup>*(Picture Source: http://www.speedbumpsandhumps.com/premium-rubber-wheelstops?st-t=sbhgoogshop&gclid=CjwKCAiAnsnjBRB6EiwATkM1XlyFCNWpi49_YaWumjP4MSDC-mx7acSCQEkBYTXZQ0dg58JYt69O_RoCGR0QAvD_BwE)*</sup>

I do not think you want the possibility of this happening in your garage.

[image]

<sup>*(Picture Source: http://www.mosesinsurance.com/blog/entryid/9194/car-vs-parking-barrier-pic-of-the-week)*</sup>

Comment: It is a good alternative but I think that is exactly what he wants to happen in his garage, **Stopping the car before it goes through the bedroom wall**.  A car traveling fast enough to do that would go right over a surface barrier curb and into the wall.

Comment: @michael-karas: thanks for the reply, that would be nice as an indicator to a driver, however, in the worst case something happens to the accelerator, I rather that happen to the garage than my body =)